# IIS renew option missing for self-signed certificate

Tags: iis

does anyone know why the "Renew" button is missing in IIS 7 ? It's a self-signed certificate and I'd like to renew it. Is is because it's  self-signed ? I have another certificate within IIS and it was signed by our internal Root CA and I can see the renew button.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a button does not make sense. Renewing a certificate typically means generating a new certificate request (and possibly automatically sending it to a CA). A self-signed certificate does not have a CA to sign it so there is no point in generating a certificate request: just generate a new self-signed certificate with the same name.